# Maintaining GraphAttributes with GraphCopy::initByCC in OGDF

Tags: c++, gml-geographic-markup-lan, ogdf

I am trying to use OGDF to perform some processing on graphs loaded from GML files.  These graphs are only meaningful if the node labels are maintained.  Unfortunately, OGDF does not make it easy to keep node attributes like labels, since they are maintained in a separate data structure called `GraphAttributes`.  My problem is that `GraphAttributes` associates node labels with node *indices*, which are not maintained by some of the graph transformations I need to use.

One of the transformations I need to perform on the Graphs is to split up each connected subgraph in a GML file.  Loading the graph and its node labels is simple:

```
ogdf::Graph graph;
ogdf::GraphAttributes attributes(graph, ogdf::GraphAttributes::nodeLabel);
ogdf::GraphIO::readGML(attributes, graph, FILENAME);

// this gives the correct label of the first node in the graph
attributes.label(graph.firstNode());
```

Similarly, OGDF provide the `CCsInfo` class to find the connected subgraphs of a graph.  Since, I want to work with these subgraphs independently, I use the `GraphCopy::initByCC` method to create separate `Graph` instances.

```
ogdf::CCsInfo info(graph);
ogdf::GraphCopy copy(graph);
ogdf::EdgeArray< ogdf::edge > edgeArray(graph);
// where i (int) is the number of the connected subgraph to copy
copy.initByCC(info, i, edgeArray);

// this now gives the wrong label for the first node in copy
attributes.label(copy.firstNode());
```

This works, and `copy` contains only the nodes and edges of the connected subgraph.  However, the indices of the nodes in the copy are different from the indices of the nodes in the original graph.  This means that the mapping of labels to nodes in the `attributes` object do not apply to the nodes in `copy`.

Is there a way to perform the same transformation on the `attributes` object so that I can get the correct labels for the nodes in the copied connected subgraph?

Comment: The [tag:gml] tag is for the Game Maker Language, not Geographic Markup Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this isn't as difficult as I thought.  The key piece I was missing is that you can use the `GraphCopy::original` method to get the node with the index from the original graph and then use that node to get the label.

```
// get the correct label for the first node of the GraphCopy object copy
attributes.label(copy.original(copy.firstNode()));
```